# How to make a custom menu in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I am new to Drupal and I want to make a Metro-style set of shortcuts to webapps in my Drupal 7 installation.
[image]

I want to make it dynamic, so anyone user with permissions can edit them in Drupal.

From what I see, I need the following fields:

```
Icon URL / Icon Image
Title
Body
Color
URL
```

So, should I create custom type `"My Custom Menu"` and use `Views module` to retrieve them and a `views-MYVIEW.tpl.php` file? Or can this be done in other simpler way.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a Node and views to achieve this. I don't think you need a tpl for this, I think some css will do just fine.

1. Just create your Node with those fields
2. Create your view as an unordered list
3. I would make the order Color (hidden), url (hidden), Global: custom text, Image, title, body, Global: Custom text
4. Set your css on the views row to float left
5. set your css on the views row to 50%, you might need some adjusting here to allow for the padding
6. Then just adjust your css to get the other elements in place

For the first global custom text

1. remove the label
2. Go to the style accordion and set the *Customize field HTML* to None
3. Go to the style accordion and set the *Customize field and label wrapper HTML* to None
4. Set the text to something like

```html
<div class="[color_field]"><a href="[url_field]">
```

For the second global custom text

1. remove the label
2. Go to the style accordion and set the *Customize field HTML* to None
3. Go to the style accordion and set the *Customize field and label wrapper HTML* to None
4. Set the text to something like

```html
</a></div>
```

The Global Custom text fields will create a wrapper around all of the fields within the views row for your color and link. Look at your *Replacement Patterns* accordion for the names of your fields in the view, I've used color_field and url_field as placeholders above

Comment: There are some words that I didn't comprehend, like Global. I've been able to do it with Views with some testing, now I see all the fields and removed all the labels of the fields and added css classes. Now I am going to modify the theme's css. One thing I don't know how to do is to use the "color" field inside CSS, maybe I will have to use JS for it to work

Comment: I am reading your answer better, to see if I can make the color thing happen

Comment: What is a Global Custom Text and how do you make replacements?

Comment: Oh I see now, Custom Text is a type when adding a field in the view. I was very confused before. I would vote you many times if I could. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use Views and then style using css. In your view format use either GRID or MASONRY API to achieve the metro layout and show FIELDS. Use the Fields to fetch your desired content from the published content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use special content type and view to get nodes in that type as other people suggested. Also you can use views_get_view_result()

https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view_result/7

To just get array of nodes and loop trough them on your own, without using any template files. This way you can use totally your HTML and just print out values from results array this function returned.

But, you can do it totally different way. If you are showing this to i.e. your home page you can add all those field describing your menu to home content type and you can use field collection module which allows you to repeat group of fields. So you can make a group of all fields describing single menu item and make it repeatable. And inside your home template file you'll simply get an array of those field groups / menu item objects.

https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection